# Regex remove everything except what I search for

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++, I have a file that contains hundreds of lines like:

`Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2\KB946503]`

`Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2\KB946504]`

I want to find the KB numbers and replace the entire document with the KB number, so it looks like this:

`KB946503`

`KB946504`

So far I can find the KB numbers using `(?=\b\w+\b)\w*kb\w*` but I do not know what to put in the replace field, I've tried `\1` and `$1` but that doesn't work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^.*\b(KB\d+)\]$
```

And replace with `\1`.

The regex will find all lines that end with `KB`+`digits`+`]`, and the `KBxxxxxx` will be restored with the `\1` backreference to the captured substring.

[image]

If you just want to find the last `KBxxxx` on a line, use

```
^.*\b(KB\d+).*$
```

To remove all texts before a KB, use

```
^[\s\S]*?\b(KB\d+).*$
```

However, the "tail" should be remove manually.

Comment: What about if the KB number was in a paragraph, say like this http://snag.gy/JGA8g.jpg and I wanted to get rid of the whole paragraph except the KB number?

Comment: Use `^.*\b(KB\d+).*$` and replace with `\1`.

Comment: That would get rid of the lines that contain the KB number and leave the remainder of the paragraph, instead of deleting the entire paragraph and keeping the KB number?

Comment: You won't be able to do that nicely (=effeciently). Use `^[\s\S]*?\b(KB\d+).*$` and replace with `\1`. The bottom will still contain the remains of the whole document, it will be easy to remove it manually.